# GA4 php filter doesn't apply

Tags: php, filter, google-analytics-4

I have a php with a GA4 request. It does spit out a response but it is not what we want to see as it seems like the filter is being completely ignored.
We are basing the filter on the JSON we get from ga-dev-tools.google - in the tool, the results seem a lot more reasonable than what we see.

Is our filter maybe wrong?? We use the following code

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\MetricType;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\FilterExpression;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter\StringFilter;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\RunReportResponse;

$property_id = '3XXXXXXXXXX';
$service_account_key_file_path = 'credentials.json';

$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
    'credentials' => $service_account_key_file_path
]);


$response = $client->runReport(
    [
        'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
        'dimensions' => [
            new Dimension(['name' => 'country']),
            new Dimension(['name' => 'pagePath'])
        ],
        'metrics' => [new Metric(['name' => 'screenPageViews'])],
        'dateRanges' => [
            new DateRange([
                'start_date' => '30daysAgo',
                'end_date' => 'yesterday',
            ])
        ],        
        'dimensionFilter' => new FilterExpression([
            'filter' => new Filter([
                'field_name' => 'pagePath',
                'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
                    'match_type' => MatchType::EXACT,
                    'value' => '/de/asubpage/'
                ])
            ])
        ])
    ]
);

// Print results of an API call.
print 'Report result: ' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
        . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The json filter looks like this, and it's what we need

```
{"dimensions":[{"name":"country"},{"name":"pagePath"}],"metrics":[{"name":"screenPageViews"}],"dateRanges":[{"startDate":"30daysAgo","endDate":"yesterday"}],"dimensionFilter":{"filter":{"stringFilter":{"matchType":"EXACT","value":"/de/asubpage/"},"fieldName":"pagePath"}},"metricAggregations":["TOTAL"]}
```

[ga-dev-tools result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCMQD.png)

[the weird results the code above gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgxNJ.png)

EDIT: Alright, got the error. It was the match type which should have been

```
'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::EXACT,
```